# Create NSString from char array with \0 characters in it?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, null, char, byte

I'm trying to initialize a simple `NSString` from an unsigned char array (ASCII encoded). The problem is, that there are some `\0`s in the array as delimiters. If I use

```
[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:bytes length:length encoding:NSASCIIEncoding];
```

I only get the part up to the first `\0`. Is there a way to get the amount of bytes specified in the length parameter even if there are `\0`s?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entire array makes into the string, it is just that when you try displaying it only the portion up to the initial `\0` is shown.

Here is code to illustrate this point:

```
unsigned char data[] = "hello\0world";
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:data length:sizeof(data) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
NSLog(@"%@", [str substringFromIndex:6]);
```

This produces the following log output:

```
hello
world
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Do you know a flexible way to log a string like that? I wouldn't mind replacing the \0 characters with a placeholder (like '?') for this purpose. I could loop over the char array and do that. Or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: Actually `[str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\0" withString:@"?"];` works fine.